# How make bag delimiters more big using stmaryrd package?

Tags: math-mode, packages, math-operators, delimiters, stmaryrd

I am using the `stmaryrd`  package and I have to increase the size of "bag" bracket, but unfortunately the usual commands `\big`, `\Big`, `\biggl`, `\Biggl`, `\left`, `\right` do not work, so that I thought to put a specific question here to ask for a solution:  I point out I tried to use what illustrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202753/296807) but unfortunately it does not work.

Hoping the question would be more clear I point out I have written something like this

```
\big\Lbag\Lbag x\Rbag\big\Rbag
```

without fraction into the argument.

The code I am using follows:

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
$$
\biggl\Lbag\Lbag x\Rbag\biggl\Rbag
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you say you are using stix, but your code (which is far from minimal) loads \usepackage{amsfonts}  not stix , it also does not appear to have any example use of the characters you are asking about.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, my bad: I was referring to stmaryrd package. Forgive my confusion.

Comment: please edit your example to make it more reasonable for people to trace. Do you _need_ `\usepackage{caption}`  to show the issue for example? and add an example of the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I simplify the code putting all package I am using. I do not understand unfortunately how I could use caption package to show the problem. However I can reaffirm that I would simply increase the size of \Lbag and \Rbag delimiters as I do for standard delimiters using the commands \big,\Big,\biggl,\Biggl,\left and \right which now do not works: e.g. If I put the command $\big\Lbag\Lbag x\Rbag\big\Rbag$ then simply $\Lbag\Lbag x\Rbag\Rbag$ appears and the compilator give an error. I hope now the problem is more clear.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro A minimal working example should only have the package necessary to reproduce the problem, not all your packages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I put all packages because I cannot know if a proposed solution can be incompatibile with respect others packages I am using: however if you believe it is better you can modify the example code.

Comment: That's not how this works … It is *your* job to remove packages one by one: Does the problem still persist? Remove another one. A **minimal working example** is exactly that: Code reduced as much as possible, which still compiles and shows your problem.

Comment: @Ingmar I did: this appears to be the shortest and least error-prone code possible.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Do you really need the geometry package to reproduce a problem with a font?

Comment: Also your question starts with `I am using the stix package`, but your code does not. Can you unify your question text and your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character isn't defined as extensible in fonts I have seen, but if you really need it you could apply scaling

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd,graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\[
\mathopen{\scalebox{2}{$\Lbag$}}\Lbag x\Rbag\mathclose{\scalebox{2}{$\Rbag$}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution: it works perfectly. Thanks for your assistance: see you soon. :-)